# static variables keep values from previous launch

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

My j2me application call `destroyApp()` and `notifyDestroyed()` when it wants to be closed
when I run it on blackberry, in the second launch the static variables will have the same values they had in previous run.

Why they don't get the initial value? How can I make sure the application initialize static variables?

Answer (score 3):

This [discussion at Blackberry support forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Static-fields/td-p/427417) suggests that it is a known issue with BlackBerry MIDlets - at least with those using static push registries. Workarounds they suggest are either re-define static variables in `startApp` or get rid of static push.

This post looks worth extensive quoting, since there is a nice code example and issue analysis:

> The simplest example I could come up with is this:
>
> ```
> public class BasicMIDlet extends MIDlet {
>
>     private static byte myByte = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
>
>     public void startApp() {
>         System.out.println("My byte: " + myByte);
>         myByte = Byte.MAX_VALUE;
>         notifyDestroyed();
>     }
>
>     public void pauseApp() {
>     }
>
>     public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> You would expect myByte to output to -128 every time the app starts,
>   but this is my output:
>
> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------
>
> Starting BBTest
> Started BBTest(159)
> Foreground BBTest(157)
> My byte: -128                          <------------
> Foreground net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(83)
> Exit BBTest(159)
> Starting BBTest
> Started BBTest(160)
> Foreground BBTest(157)
> My byte: 127                          <------------
> Foreground net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(83)
> Exit BBTest(160)
> Starting BBTest
> Started BBTest(161)
> Foreground BBTest(157)
> My byte: 127                          <------------
> Foreground net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(83)
> Exit BBTest(161)
> --------------------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> I have noticed something, if I remove the static push registries, the
>   application behaves normally and outputs -128 every time. An yes, I
>   have the same feeling that a MIDlet runs on top of a RIMlet, and in
>   the case the midlet defines push registries, the RIMlet is running all
>   the time. So my question now is, are there any solutions other than
>   initializing the static variables on every run (because there are
>   roughly >1000 such members in my app)

Comment: Has RIM acknowledged the issue ? If yes, what is the issue number for it ?

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti did you follow the link in the answer - one that is labelled "discussion at Blackberry support forums"?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, blackberry midlets retain the values of static variables. This is an issue, and the only way I see to fix it is that in the startup we need to assign null values to the static values. For example if a static var is declared like:
public static String State = null;
And in the life cycle of the middle the value is set to "closed";
Then in the next startup of the application, the value remains "closed" instead of null.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you mean "in the second launch the static variables will ***not*** have the same values they had in previous run".

Static variables can only maintain their value through the lifetime of the app.  The app ends when `destroyApp()`/`notifyDestroyed()` is called, so the values are lost!

To persist state over multiple runs, use the [`RecordStore`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html).